Power BI - Imported data from SQL that has multiple records for one identifier
I'll try to explain as well as I can.
I've imported data from SQL from one of our business tables. In our table, and via the query, we have 2900 records, of which 2100 are unique customers. The records in our table are based on agent input, and consist of

Workitem number
Customer Account number
Opportunity (customer's debt value)
Secured (how much debt was secured in the interaction)
Cash collected (how much cash was collected)

I am trying to build a simple visualisation in Power BI to sum up each of the opportunity, secured, and cash collected. Cash collected is easy, as the column either has values or empty cells.
The problem with both secured and opportunity is, they can have the same value duplicated.
Example:
Customer has 2 records in the table for workitem.



Record
Workitem
Customer
Opportunity
Secured
Collected




Record one
1
ABC
750
750
0


Record two
2
ABC
750
150
150



The customer paid 150 (record two) and setup a payment plan (record one) for the whole balance.
The issue with this is that when i am summing the columns, I am getting

1500 as opportunity
900 as secured
150 as collected

I want the values to be

750 opportunity
750 secured (the secured value cannot be more than opportunity so should be the highest secured value for the partitioned account or the same as the opportunity, which ever is lower)
150 as collected.

Collected gives me no issues.
The other quirk to the data is that customers may appear in the hard data repeatedly. This customer as an example is from YEARWEEK '202448' or the 48th Week of 2024. I am wanting to introduce a wider query to include data from previous weeks too, so I want to take this into account.
So basically, I want a calculated derived column that gives

Total opportunity for all cases, but when there are duplicated entries for the account in that week I only want to return the sum of the opportunities once for each distinct account
Total secured for each cases, as in point 1, but considering the secured must be less than or equal to the opportunity value (if it's higher to default to match the opportunity)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
